# How to write regex 'line' contains string

Tags: regex

I have string:

```
one line
second line
magic line foo
third line
```

How to match full line with foo only using keyword `foo`?

So, I can match `foo` using `/foo/g`, but I don't know how to match full line.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can try this:

```
^.*foo.*$
```

it will match full line containing foo

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJRoDh/1)