# Nginx map: regex to check substring

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx service that serves an application. This application sends requests often, because of that, there are a lot of log messages inside my `access.log` file.

For that reason, I'm trying to create a [Conditional Logging](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#enabling-conditional-logging) to avoid to save these unnecessary log messages.

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#enabling-conditional-logging), I've tried to create a regex to check if the request contains a substring, but it did not work.

I believe my `$request` variable should be a request like this one:

```
GET /catalog-dash/_reload-hash HTTP/1.1
```

I would like to check if my `$request` variable contains the `_reload-hash` substring.

I've created the code below, but it did not work, unfortunately.

```
map $request $loggable {
    ~/_reload-hash/  0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

If someone could help me, I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're trying to match a string that ends with a `/`. The example you give in your question does not. Also, If you are not interested in the `GET` and `HTTP/1.1` bits, you could use [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your observation. I've changed my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe before asking the question I did not use the correct keys to search the answer on the internet.

Some minutes after asking the original question I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48742663/8447990) answer that has solved my problem.

I send below the changes I did to work and I hope it could help others in the future.

```
map $request_uri $loggable {
    ~^.*_reload-hash.*$  0;
    default 1;
}
```

Thank you Richard for your tip of using `$request_uri` instead of `$request`.